# Why am I getting an error stated that k is not defined, even though i have returned it?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Why am I getting an error stated that k is not defined, even though i have returned it?

```
import pyautogui
def askpass():
    password = pyautogui.password(text='Enter password for the database:', title='', default='', mask='*')
    if password=='root':
        print('password correct')
    else:
        askpass()
    k=password
    return k

askpass()
print(k)
```

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: You meant to write: `k = askpass()`

Comment: thanks quamrana for your answer but now after i used 'k=askpass()' what happens is that whenever i give wrong password initially but correct password the next time, the wrong password is stored in k not the new(correct) password , help me with this

Comment: you return a *value* not the variable. `k` is a local variable to `askpass`. Just because it is involved in a `return` statement doesn't mean the caller will get a `k` variable in it's own scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
I've missed the recursive `askpass()` when reading the code, if you entered the wrong password you would go into another call of the same function but that call's return doesn't get assigned to password. Now I don't recommend using recursion either in here because you just keep on adding up functions call, but I recommend doing this with a while loop like this:

```py
def askpass():
    password = ""
    while password != "root":
        password = pyautogui.password(text='Enter password for the database:', title='', default='', mask='*')
    k=password
    return k
```

OLD:

The correct syntax for this is

```py
import pyautogui
def askpass():
    password = pyautogui.password(text='Enter password for the database:', title='', default='', mask='*')
    if password=='root':
        print('password correct')
    else:
        password=askpass()
    k=password
    return k

k = askpass()
print(k)
```

or

```py
print(askpass())
```

When you return a variable, it returns it's value that you can then get like written above.

(That's how you can imagine it, but in python what actually happens the function returns a reference to a object that can then be assigned to a variable)

Comment: thanks for your answer but now after i used 'k=askpass()' what happens is that whenever i give wrong password initially but correct password the next time, the wrong password is stored in k not the new(correct) password , help me with this

Comment: thanks a lot it worked i am so happy to use this website (ps, this is my first question on stackoverflow)